# to access camera view and capture image in ios5 which framework is used?

Tags: iphone, ios5, avfoundation

Before ios 5 AVFoundationFramework is used but it is not working with ios5 storyboard Application 
gives linking errors like
even if i add the framework 
Please help me.

Below given method gives me top 3 or 4 errors.

```
  - (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {

        void (^deviceConnectedBlock)(NSNotification *) = ^(NSNotification *notification) {
            AVCaptureDevice *device = [notification object];

            BOOL sessionHasDeviceWithMatchingMediaType = NO;
            NSString *deviceMediaType = nil;
            if ([device hasMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio])
                deviceMediaType = AVMediaTypeAudio;
            else if ([device hasMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo])
                deviceMediaType = AVMediaTypeVideo;

            if (deviceMediaType != nil) {
                for (AVCaptureDeviceInput *input in [session inputs])
                {
                    if ([[input device] hasMediaType:deviceMediaType]) {
                        sessionHasDeviceWithMatchingMediaType = YES;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!sessionHasDeviceWithMatchingMediaType) {
                    NSError *error;
                    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
                    if ([session canAddInput:input])
                        [session addInput:input];
                }               
            }

            if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(captureManagerDeviceConfigurationChanged:)]) {
                [delegate captureManagerDeviceConfigurationChanged:self];
            }           
        };
        void (^deviceDisconnectedBlock)(NSNotification *) = ^(NSNotification *notification) {                       
            if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(captureManagerDeviceConfigurationChanged:)]) {
                [delegate captureManagerDeviceConfigurationChanged:self];
            }           
        };

        NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [self setDeviceConnectedObserver:[notificationCenter addObserverForName:AVCaptureDeviceWasConnectedNotification object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:deviceConnectedBlock]];
        [self setDeviceDisconnectedObserver:[notificationCenter addObserverForName:AVCaptureDeviceWasDisconnectedNotification object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:deviceDisconnectedBlock]];
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
        [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(deviceOrientationDidChange) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
        orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
    }
    return self;
}

    Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureDeviceInput", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AVCamCaptureManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureStillImageOutput", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AVCamCaptureManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AVCamCaptureManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureDevice", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AVCamCaptureManager.o
  "_AVCaptureDeviceWasConnectedNotification", referenced from:
      -[AVCamCaptureManager init] in AVCamCaptureManager.o
  "_AVCaptureDeviceWasDisconnectedNotification", referenced from:
      -[AVCamCaptureManager init] in AVCamCaptureManager.o
  "_AVMediaTypeAudio", referenced from:
      ___27-[AVCamCaptureManager init]_block_invoke_0 in AVCamCaptureManager.o
      -[AVCamCaptureManager micCount] in AVCamCaptureManager.o
      -[AVCamCaptureManager(InternalUtilityMethods) audioDevice] in AVCamCaptureManager.o
  "_AVMediaTypeVideo", referenced from:
      ___27-[AVCamCaptureManager init]_block_invoke_0 in AVCamCaptureManager.o
      -[AVCamCaptureManager captureStillImage] in AVCamCaptureManager.o
      -[AVCamCaptureManager cameraCount] in AVCamCaptureManager.o
      -[AVCamCaptureManager(InternalUtilityMethods) cameraWithPosition:] in AVCamCaptureManager.o
      -[AVCamViewController(InternalMethods) convertToPointOfInterestFromViewCoordinates:] in AVCamViewController.o
      ___27-[AVCamCaptureManager init]_block_invoke_0 in AVCamCaptureManager.o
      -[AVCamCaptureManager captureStillImage] in AVCamCaptureManager.o
      -[AVCamCaptureManager cameraCount] in AVCamCaptureManager.o
      -[AVCamCaptureManager(InternalUtilityMethods) cameraWithPosition:] in AVCamCaptureManager.o
      -[AVCamViewController(InternalMethods) convertToPointOfInterestFromViewCoordinates:] in AVCamViewController.o
  "_AVVideoCodecJPEG", referenced from:
      -[AVCamCaptureManager setupSession] in AVCamCaptureManager.o
  "_AVVideoCodecKey", referenced from:
      -[AVCamCaptureManager setupSession] in AVCamCaptureManager.o
  "_CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetCleanAperture", referenced from:
      -[AVCamViewController(InternalMethods) convertToPointOfInterestFromViewCoordinates:] in AVCamViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AVCamViewController.o
  "_AVLayerVideoGravityResize", referenced from:
      -[AVCamViewController(InternalMethods) convertToPointOfInterestFromViewCoordinates:] in AVCamViewController.o
  "_AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect", referenced from:
      -[AVCamViewController(InternalMethods) convertToPointOfInterestFromViewCoordinates:] in AVCamViewController.o
  "_AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill", referenced from:
      -[AVCamViewController viewDidLoad] in AVCamViewController.o
      -[AVCamViewController(InternalMethods) convertToPointOfInterestFromViewCoordinates:] in AVCamViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ALAssetsLibrary", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ImageViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks in advance
**EDIT:**
Problem is solved.
some changes in app settings like change in search header path etc.

Comment: It's perfectly valid to answer your own question, especially if the information could be of use to others.

Comment: thanks @Diziet i try to update my post as frequently as possible

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To me:

Simply add AVFoundation Framework to Linked FrameWork and Libraries in Target tab.

Answer (score 3):

But for me `CoreMedia.framework` along with `AVFoundation.framework`, helped.

Answer (score 0):

please add . the following frame works into your project and import in target class

```
<AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>
 <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```